# Track multiple UITextField's text length

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I want to track 2 `UITextField`'s, if they are empty, Done button is disabled. In `viewDidLoad` I've disabled button, because all `UITextField`'s are empty. All text fields have delegate and I'm tracking their state in `-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

```
if (textField == self.emailTextField) {
        if (self.passwordTextField.hasText && [string length] > 0) {
            [self.loginButton setEnabled:YES];
        }
        else {
            [self.loginButton setEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
    else if (textField == self.passwordTextField) {
        if (self.emailTextField.hasText && [string length] > 0) {
            [self.loginButton setEnabled:YES];
        }
        else {
            [self.loginButton setEnabled:NO];
        }
    }

    return YES;
```

I know that this is not best solution to track, because now I have problem when someone only delete character, string is empty and button is disabled. Thanks in advance for finding best solution with me.

Comment: you can check the length of self.textField.text instead of the string length, but I recommend you to use Reactive Cocoa

Comment: Yes, but the problem is next case: if text field is empty, I type one character, it still detects it is empty, because should method is triggered just before previous string is replaced by new(one character).

Comment: @Stefan is not it better to check directly when you click on the button? the button is always enabled, when click on button you check textField.text.length and if is 0 return an uialertview to comunicate that the textfields are empty

Comment: Yes, but specification requires that button is disabled if this two fields are not populated...

Comment: it's true, i didn't remember that. What if you check if textField has some text, and then create a new string with [textField.text stringByReplacing...] and check the length of that string? Btw, I think that ReactiveCocoa is perfect for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the delegate. You can connect the IBAction "edit did change" for the text fields.. and inside of it you do

```
- (IBAction)textFieldChanged:(UITextField *)sender {
    [self.loginButton setEnabled:(self.passwordTextField.hasText && self.emailTextField.hasText)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you should take into account the length of the text after the change.

There are many examples here on SO on how to do that. Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *resultString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                                     withString:string];

    size_t emailLen = [textField isEqual:_emailTextField] ? 
        resultString.text.length : _emailTextField.text.length;

    size_t pwdLen = [textField isEqual:_passwordTextField] ? 
        resultString.text.length : _passwordTextField.text.length;

    self.loginButton.enabled = emailLen && pwdLen;

    return YES;
}
```

Inside this method one could also perform some UI actions (red color of email text if it doesn't appear to be valid...). But if you need to check only the length of the texts (after edit) then Robertos answer is more elegant.